# Using Azure For Global Users

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a project whereby the web site (all components are hosted in Azure) will have both US and international users. We are using Blob and Table storage for 99% of the data. What I do not understand is how to setup global instances, including multiple tables, etc, and keep everything in sync. Say a user logs into the site from France, how can I ensure they will always hit the same data center (which implies the same Storage instance)? If they hit a different storage instance, their data will not be there and/or stale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Compute and Storage are affinitized to a specific data center. There's no *global compute* or *global storage* deployment concept.

Having said that: You'll typically host your human-facing app (e.g. web app) in a single data center. Usually, latency between browser and server is not much of an issue if only a relatively-small quantity of data is moving between the two. The majority of bandwidth is typically between web server and app servers and/or database instances. And in Azure, data doesn't necessarily need to be colocated in the same data center as the web app (though it's the ideal scenario from latency + egress bandwidth cost perspective).

If you want Compute in multiple data centers, you'd need to have a higher-level mechanism doing some type of load balancing for you (such as Azure's Traffic Manager). However, even with Traffic Manager's "closest" setting, you're not really guaranteed that a user in France will hit the W. Europe vs. N. Europe data center. You'd always have to plan for a visitor hitting *any* data center. This is why it's much simpler to deal with Compute in a single data center.

Regarding data: If your Compute is in a single data center, there's no need (other than disaster recovery) to write data to multiple data centers. If you *do* decide to deploy Compute to multiple data centers, you'll need your own method for syncing data. For Azure blobs & table storage, you can consider some type of command pattern (e.g. CQRS) where your operations are queue driven. This allows you to process each queued data operation against multiple storage accounts across different data centers.

Now, you might have data sovereignty issues, where data *must* reside in a specific data center for specific customers, based on their geo. Again, you'll need to implement this in the app layer. One thought on this is to affinitize a user with a particular data center when they get set up (and just store the data center mapping in a single database along with your web tier). At this point, when a visitor logs in, you can easily look up their correct data center and, within their browsing session, access their data from the specific data center.